# SIP library for watchOS 5 development kit

Tags: ios, sip, apple-watch, sip-server, watchos-5

In my case, I need to make an in-house communication system using Apple watches ( watch to watch, using WiFi only).
There I'm planning to use SIP protocol for voice communication

*And already found the SIP Library [linphone-swift-demo](https://github.com/cwliu/linphone-swift-demo) And it is not supported the WatchOS

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for off-site resources is off topic.  I think you will struggle to develop this on WatchOS5.  You might be able to do it on WatchOS6 as it has expanded background execution, but it will still probably be tricky.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think so too, Thanks